# How to maintain page background image zoom fixed? CSS

Tags: css, background-image

I know how to set page background like;

```
body{
  background-color: blue;
  background-image: url(imagename.ext);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
```

The page is subject to zoom. Using the browser, user can zoom in and zoom out. But the background image may not zoom-in or zoom-out. It may remain as such, in it's default size. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: first answer is not in perfect form you can see there, but its link is really useful and perfect that's it. Just for help and make easy for person who need its solution. have you any other way then you can also paste

Answer (score 0):

You can use css:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Little unrelated to question but that might help someone.  I'll go with the use of a jquery plugin like http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ for this.

I have always had speed issues with having full page static background (as Anup Jangid's answer) through css. It makes scrolling of the page very slow and slugish.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a native clean way to achieve what you're asking. This method should work but you may get some (perhaps acceptable) flickering as the size adjusts after the browser zooms.

Specify background-size:widthpx heightpx and when the browser zooms you need to detect the zoom scale (see [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)) and set the width px and height px of the background image accordingly.